# Terminology and technique for repeated pairwise removal of elements of posets: "Collapsibility" of a "face poset"

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, order-theory

Let $P$ be a poset, or partially ordered set. Let $\le$ denote the reflexive order on $P$, and $<$ the corresponding irreflexive order. Let the phrase "*a maximal pair*" in $P$ refer to an
ordered pair $(u,v)$ of elements in $P$ such that

- $u>v$,
- $u$ is a maximal element of $P$, and
- $v$ is a maximal element of the subposet $P\setminus\{u\}$.

We say a subposet $P'$ of $P$ is *obtained by elementary collapse* from $P$, if
$P' = P \setminus \{u,v\}$ for some maximal pair $(u,v)$ of $P$. We say $P$ is *collapsible* if there is a sequence
$$
P = P_0 \supset P_1 \supset \cdots \supset P_{k-1} \supset P_k = 
\left\{\ast\right\}
$$
of subposets of $P$, in which $P_i$ is obtained by elementary collapse from $P_{i-1}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$.

My questions are:

- I needed to prepare by myself the terminology for *maximal pairs*, *elementary collapse*, and *collapsiblity*; is there any better, more common way to refer to them?
- I am working on proving collapsibility for a class of posets, **conjecturally** being the face posets of some convex polytopes. Are there any general ways to prove collapsibility of a poset, assuming or not assuming realizations as convex polytopes?

Comment: So you have a finite partial order, and you just remove maximal elements one by one (each time maximal in the "collapsed" order) until you've cleared up the entire thing. What am I missing? Also what does $v$ matter in the choice of collapsing the order? You just remove $u$ which is a maximal element, and that's it.

Comment: Note that: $P'=P\setminus\left\{u,v\right\}$. And $v$ must be maximal in $P\setminus \left\{ u \right\} $. So $\left\{x > y < z\right\}$ (in which x and z are incomparable) is not collapsible.

Comment: Is the poset $P=\{0,1\}$ ordered by $0<1$ collapsible? As I understand $(1,0)$ is a maximal pair, but $P \setminus\{1,0\} = \emptyset \neq \{*\}$ as you demand. - If I understand correctly, one simple criterion for $P$ to be collapsible is that it has an odd number of points in the base set.

Comment: No. It is NOT collapsible. and yes,that's very important necessary condition.

Comment: In fact, in case of ranked posets (=all maximal chains has the same finite length), $P$ must have *Euler characteristic* 1.